# Grouping best practices for list with international data

Tags: internationalisation, metro, windows-8

I have a grouped list of items sorted alphabetically. Groups are created from the first character of each item title.

All characters that not belongs to any alphabet are grouped into a unique group (things like `0`, `1`, `@`, `.` are grouped together into `#`).

**Question(s):**

- How do you handle grouping in Cyrillic, Thaï, Indonesian, etc.?
- How do you handle grouping in a list with Latin and non-Latin items?

This question is related to a GroupView in a Windows Store App (Windows 8), but can be applied to all kind of devices.

*Edit:*
For reference, we have to support these languages/alphabets:

- All Latin,
- Norwegian, Swedish, Finnish,
- Cyrillic,
- Greek,
- Arabian
- Thai, Indonesian, Korean

Answer (score 4):

When in a localized environment, the best thing you can do is to group according to the local alphabet. On my Windows Phone I use English language as localization even though my navive language is Swedish. This means the phone organize all other letters of my alphabet to the **#** just before a, b, c,...

[image]

I would like the option to set my contacts grouping according to my Swedish alphabet maiking my friends visible where I expect them to be. Åsa, Ärling and Örjan today shows up under **#** - instead of in the end where we organize these letters in Swedish.

The Swedish alphabet ends with X, Y, Z, Å, Ä, Ö. And as a consequence the Cryllic alphabet would be grouped accordingly:

[image]

### Latin and non-Latin order of items

As for Latin and non-Latin items could be tough. It really depends on which non-Latin items you have, and should be treated with care. A general rule could be to use the [Wikipedia help page on Alphabetic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Alphabetical_order) when appropriate. At least it gives you a clue how they could be organized.

> !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
>   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_'
>   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
>   ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«­®¯°±²³´µ•¸¹º»¼½¾¿
>   ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
>   ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋ
>   ŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſ
>   ǺǻǼǽǾǿ΄΅Ά·ΈΉΊΌΎΏΐ
>   ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰ
>   αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϊϋόύώ

Comment: Hi @benny-skogberg , thanks for your detailed answer. Here are my comments :

 - If country/region AND the phone language is set to language/country couple with specific alphabet, the photo contacts lists is adapted to group with these conditions : "a-z" for the current alphabet, then international characteurs, then non "alphabetic characters", then latin a-z order.

 - How do you handle grouping with asian alphabets ? It seems a bit tricky compared to latin/greek alphabet

Comment: @Christopher Asian languages is very different from our making of words through letters. I'm unfortunately not the one to tell you how to organize a chinese phone book, but I can guide you to this interesting Wikipedia article: [Chinese caracter classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification)

Answer (score 0):

Cyrillic are grouped the same way, using first character of the name. I do believe the same rules are applied to Norwegian, Swedish and Finnish. Not sure about Arabian and Thai though.

And concerning mixing several languages. I think the better way is to try to keep the languages separated: I mean, *do not mix the characters of different languages*!

As an example I've done a slightly modified iOS address book navigation scheme (original address book has no ability to show grouping for several languages unfortunately):

[image]

Or, alternatively, you may try to give users an ability to quickly switch between language groups (by swiping or by buttons, etc):

[image]